# Convert List of encoded Image to PDF

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

At first, I am converting a `PDF` file to `Image` file.

Then I make changes on the Image(converted PDF).

Now, I want to convert everything back to PDF and also have a copy in a base64 format of the PDF.

This is how I convert my PDF:

```
 Future<List<List<int>>> imageFromPdfFileFullImage(
      Future<PdfDocument> pdfFile) async {
    int height = 0, width = 0;

    final document = await pdfFile;
    im.Image imImage;
    for (int i = 1; i <= document.pagesCount; i++) {
      final page = await document.getPage(i);
      final pdfPageImage = await page.render(
          width: page.width, height: page.height, format: PdfPageFormat.JPEG);
      imImage = im.decodeJpg(pdfPageImage.bytes); // First issue in this line
      height += imImage.height;
      if (imImage.width > width) {
        width = imImage.width;
      }

      //List<Image> buffer 'package:image/image.dart'
      imageList.add(imImage);
      //List<List<int>> 'package:image/image.dart' as im
      //I want this encodeImaegList to be converted back to PDF later
      encodeImageList.add(im.encodePng(imageList[i - 1]));

      await page.close();
    }

    return encodeImageList;
  }
```

This may be useful for those who's looking to convert some pdf files to images.

I hope you can help me on my problem too. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this package, hope it helps
`https://pub.dev/packages/pdf`